# how to run a script when deploying an application to cloudControl?

Tags: deployment, cloud, cloudcontrol

I want to run some [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) tasks when deploying a PHP application on [cloudControl](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/). How can I do this?

Comment: There is the possibility to use the heroku-phing-buildpack but it is yet to be documented "how that actually works". Unless you want to figure it out yourself - which is what i am trying to right now.
The way to start is to create a new app using the following line: $ cctrlapp your_new_app_name create custom --buildpack https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-phing.git
This calls "phing stage" after pushing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you currently can't, but custom buildpack support is coming soon.